# is there any filter in ansible can mimic all() and any()?

Tags: ansible

It is surprising there is no such filter in jinja2 or ansible. What is the canonical way to mimic this in ansible? I expect to have `[True, False] | all` return False, `[True, False] | any` return True. So far for any I can use sum then check if it is greater than 0. But all is trickier I have to do `select('false') | length ==0` which looks quite stupid. Is there better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what *all* and *any* [tests](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-if-a-list-value-is-true) do e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ [True, False] is all }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ [True, False] is any }}"
```

give

```yaml
  msg: false
  msg: true
```

---

There are no such [filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html) in Ansible but you can write them e.g.

```py
shell> cat filter_plugins/list2bool.py

def fall(l):
        return all(l)

def fany(l):
        return any(l)

class FilterModule(object):
    ''' Ansible filters for operating on Boolean '''

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'fall': fall,
            'fany': fany,
            }
```

<sup>(see other [plugins](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-plugins))</sup>

These custom filters are useful in pipes, e.g. to [map](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#map) lists

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ l|map('fall')|list }}"
      vars:
        l:
          - [True, True]
          - [True, False]
          - [False, True]
          - [False, False]
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - true
  - false
  - false
  - false
```

and

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ l|map('fany')|list }}"
      vars:
        l:
          - [True, True]
          - [True, False]
          - [False, True]
          - [False, False]
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - true
  - true
  - true
  - false
```